# What should I do when I suspect account-duping and weird upvoting patterns?

Tags: discussion

I found this odd, and felt I had to ask.

User Foo asks a question, another user also named Foo answers the question within two minutes. Recieves upvote and accepted answer.

The two users with the same name from the same location is also editing each other's posts.

User Bar which is also from the same place as Foo ( I stalked their profiles. I'm a criminal. ) asks a question. Foo answers the question. Now, other random users also answers Bar's question.

After the random users posted potential answers for the question, Foo begins to act like the initial asker. Posting comments such as:

> hi @user, Thanx for the Answer:),if you don't mind Pleaes suggest me
>   changes here.

And

> hey @user can u suggest me changes here

I'm possibly WAY out of line here. But since I don't know. I find it better to ask before acting.

If i'm possibly NOT out of line. Is there a way to act on this?